# Creating a GUI with Eclipse WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm trying to make a GUI for a game I've created, originally this game was console based however I'm trying to improve my skills and add a GUI.

I've managed to add a button and add a event handler so when that button is clicked, code will run, however, I'm wondering...

Since my game was previously Console Based, where would I paste all of the code in my Main Method to the GUI part, how would I then have it print out the text I've used to a Textbox in the GUI, then how would I have it show the Buttons (In this case, Attack, Defend, or Flee).

I'm also wondering about how I'd have the code wait for a users Click on one of the buttons, then how I'd have the code run when that button is clicked.

Here's the code I have in my Main Method. It's pretty lengthy.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random Randint = new Random();

        int level = playerstats.level;
        int experiance = playerstats.experiance;
        int defence = playerstats.defence;
        int levelcap = playerstats.levelcap;
        int attackBase = playerstats.attackbase;
        int agility = playerstats.agility;
        String location = "Hell";
        int health = 100;

        int defended = 0;
        Boolean alive = true;
        if (alive = true) {
            while (alive) {
                if (experiance >= levelcap) {
                    level++;
                    experiance = experiance * 2;
                    attackBase = attackBase + 5;
                }
                boolean enemyalive = false;
                byte Choice;
                int fleeattempt;
                System.out.println("You're still alive. Surprising.");
                System.out.println("Your current level is " + level + " you require " + (levelcap - experiance)
                        + " more experiance to level up");
                System.out.println("Press enter to continue walking");
                reader.nextLine();
                System.out.println("You've encountered an enemy!");
                int enemyencountered = Randint.nextInt(1);
                if (enemyencountered == 0) {
                    enemyencountered = enemyencountered + 1;
                } else {
                }
                enemyalive = true;
                while (enemyalive) {
                    switch (enemyencountered) {
                    case 1:
                        int enemyhealth = goblin.health;
                        int enemydefence = goblin.defence;
                        String enemyname = goblin.name;
                        int enemyagility = goblin.agility;
                        while (enemyalive) {
                            if (defended == 1) {
                                defence = defence - 5;
                                defended = 0;
                            }
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            System.out.println("You have encountered a " + enemyname);
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            System.out.println("You have " + health + " remaining HP");
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            System.out.println("It has " + enemyhealth + " Remaining HP");
                            System.out.println("1. attack");
                            System.out.println("2. Inspect Enemy");
                            System.out.println("3. Defend");
                            System.out.println("4. Flee");
                            System.out.println("5. Quit.");
                            Choice = reader.nextByte();
                            switch (Choice) {
                                case 1:
                                    int Hit = attackBase - enemydefence;
                                    int attack = Randint.nextInt(Hit);
                                    System.out.println("You hit the enemy for " + attack);
                                    enemyhealth = enemyhealth - attack;
                                    if (enemyhealth <= 0) {
                                        System.out.println(enemyname + " has been killed! Welldone!");
                                        enemyalive = false;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    System.out.println(enemyname + " has " + enemydefence + " defence");
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    System.out.println("You prepare yourself for the enemies attack!");
                                    defence = defence + 5;
                                    defended = 1;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    System.out.println("You're trying to flee. Coward!");
                                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                                    fleeattempt = Randint.nextInt(agility);
                                    if (fleeattempt > enemyagility) {
                                        System.out.println("You successfuly Escape!");
                                        enemyalive = false;
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("You accidently fall over while trying to escape.");
                                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                                        health = health - 5;
                                        System.out.println("You lose 5 HP.");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    System.out.println("Quitting, eh?... Well, bye!");
                                    alive = false;
                                    enemyalive = false;
                                    break;
                            }

                            if (enemyalive) {
                                int enemyattack;
                                enemyattack = goblin.baseattack;
                                int enemydamage = Randint.nextInt(enemyattack);
                                health = health - enemydamage;
                                System.out.println(enemyname + " Has hit you for " + enemydamage + " HP!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable names should start with a lowercase according to the Java naming conventions. It's very hard to read the code this way. Please fix.

Comment: I've made all of the Variables Lowercase.

Comment: Where is `playerstats` and `goblin` defined? This is not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Start by [reading about Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). You will learn about all the text components to display and read text.

Comment: Please limit your posts to one question per post. That being said, you should create smaller questions that don't require you to post your entire code

Comment: Sorry about the late Reply. playerstats and goblin are defined in a completely seperate Class. It doesn't have any code in it, just the Values to define those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest first start off by reading more about java swing, heck even watch and complete a tutorial on youtube. Your questions:

Question: I'm also wondering about how I'd have the code wait for a users Click on one of the buttons, then how I'd have the code run when that button is clicked.

Answer: Well when you run GUI code it does not run continuously, it waits and "listens" to the user's input. When you click this button the action "listener" or whichever listener you have implemented will run the code you want to run on the button click.

Question: Since my game was previously Console Based, where would I paste all of the code in my Main Method to the GUI part, how would I then have it print out the text I've used to a Textbox in the GUI, then how would I have it show the Buttons (In this case, Attack, Defend, or Flee).

Answer: GUI is a huge field and to figure out how you want your window to look, where and how the texts would be printed check this out:

http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/ui/features/components.html

For these buttons you can always use a JButton and you can still use 1, 2 ,3 ,4 entered from a keyboard, as to how you would press in this case, Attack, Defend, or Flee.

One more thing about the windowsbuilder is that in your case, since you have made the program already on console and you want to convert it into GUI, it might be easier, quicker and more learn worthy if you **don't use windowbuilder**. Do it manually.

Comment: It seems like this answer has answered my question. Thanks!